# Проверка текста на наличие символа jQuery

Tags: jquery

Не могу разобраться как можно проверить наличие символа в тексте с помощью jQuery. Например у меня есть `var slovo = "88+23="`. Какой функцией можно проверить, что в тексте есть символ "+" и что бы возвращало значение `true` или `false`. Думал что поможет `$.search()` но что-то не вышло.

Comment: str.indexOf('+') - возвращает значение отличное от `-1` если есть в строке

Comment: а зачем вам jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться `test`:

```
var urVar = "22+55=";
alert(/^.*\+.*$/.test(urVar))
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pfgs568w/)

Comment: тут проверка плюса, а не маска...

Comment: я показал как можно с помощью регулярного сделать, а поправить не сложно `/^.*\+.*$/`.test(urVar)

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` в помощь:

```js
var slovo = "88+23=";

if(slovo.indexOf('+') > 0 ){
  console.log('есть');
} else {
  console.log('нет');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: indexOf - не метод jquery

Comment: И поэтому он не может применяться в jQuery???!!!

Comment: вы гоните, Елена)) не понимаете основ. Вы подключили библиотеку, в которой нет необходимости, так как функция indexOf присутствует в нативном js. Да и как может функция применяться в библиотеке? Библиотека это и есть набор функций, то есть indexOf может использоваться в скрипте вкупе с другими функциями. Да и ладно, о чем это я....))))) ахаха.

Comment: Я как раз это понимаю. А вот Вы запутались в Ваших комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```js
$(function() {
 $(document).ready(function(){
      
      var res = $('.str').text().indexOf('+')+1;
      if(res!=-1){
        alert('Есть символ. Позиция символа - '+res);  
      }
      else {
        alert('Cимвола нет');  
        }
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="str">88+22=</div>
```